# retrieve last updated column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db, lastinsertid

I have a MySQL query that goes as follows (using Zend_Db):

```
 $sql = $handle->quoteInto("UPDATE board SET rank=rank+1 WHERE post_id=?", $postid);
 $handle->query($sql);
```

(Rank isn't an auto-incrementing PK).
I would like to now retrieve the value of `rank` without preforming another query.
I've tried `$handle->lastInsertId();` but it doesn't seem to work , since I didn't use MySQL's natural auto-incrementing method (I can't - `rank` is the rank of a post. I either ++ or -- it.)

Any way to do this with preforming another query? A function that will return the last changed value?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this is possible - you'll just have to do a `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes I'm affraid so: `query("SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE id = 'lastId'")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function that MySQL provides to set a value and then make it available via the [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html) C function that the `$handle->lastInsertId();` relies on.

The following is an updated version of your code snippet with the LAST_INSERT_ID changes made to it:

```
 $sql = $handle->quoteInto("UPDATE board SET rank=LAST_INSERT_ID(rank+1) WHERE post_id=?", $postid);
 $handle->query($sql);
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

HTH,

-Dipin